# AppEngine appcfg.py complains about wrong version

Tags: google-app-engine

I have updated the AppEngine SDK for Python on my Mac to version 1.9.74.266.

I need to update a Python 2.7 Standard Environment App via `appcfg.py` (which is called from a complex build script updating multiple App Engine applications) but I get the following error:

> Error 401
>   Your version of the AppEngine SDK is out-of-date. Please update your SDK ...

But this is what I just did.

What's wrong?

Comment: Is there any reason for not using [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/download) ? Try using it, to see if you have the same error.

Comment: FWIW I can't repro with the linux 1.9.74 version, things appear ok.

Comment: I have switched the project to the gcloud method.